# What is the essential difference between keyword and predeclare name in Go

Tags: go

Go has 25 keywords like if and switch that may be used only where the syntax permits; they can’t be used as names.

In addition, there are about three dozen predeclared names like int and true for built-in con- stants, types, and functions

Comment: the essential difference is that keywords are reserved and you can't use them as identifiers. predeclared identifiers can be shadowed in a lesser block

Answer (score 2):

They are just identifiers, universally available for you automatically.

Of course, you can change them since they are just predefined identifiers, not a language construct as others.

```golang
var bool int = 42
fmt.Println(bool)
// 42
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Mh7MF6If6oy